# Joomla installfile "Call to undefined method"

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm rewriting a component, and I've been following
a tutorial here: http://docs.joomla.org/Managing_Component_Updates_with_Joomla!1.6_-_Part_3

In the install file code they compare the existing installed component with the new
install file's params. The code to get the installed version is this:

`$oldRelease = $this->getParam('version');`

When I run this, it dies with the following:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method
com_mycomponentInstallerScript::getParam()`

I thought that in Joomla 1.6+ the params were accessible
automatically via the getParam?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the full script you linked to, they added a function getParam to the class. since com_mycomponentInstallerScript isn't extending an existing Joomla class, that function doesn't exist unless you define it.